# Magento two shared websites, but want to make frontend changes in one of them

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We've been using two shared websites for some time. I've used the subdirectory method as indicated here (https://www.crucialhosting.com/knowledgebase/setup-multiple-magento-stores). So both websites have a shared admin panel and share the file system.

But we want the possibility to make some changes for the second site compared to the first. The second website is for our physical store so we could decide to not allowe customers to place an order, but only show which products we have in the physical store and the actual stock levels.

I would do that by making changes in app/code or app/design, etc. But because both sites share the same files, I can't regularly change a file without making a change to both websites.

So the question is:
Do I need to setup the two sites in a different way, or is there a way to make changes in some files to differentiate results depending on the site the customer is seeing? If site = 2 then do not show the shopping cart, etc.

We're using Magento 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of providing dynamic content/features in Magento based on website.

Below are two easy ways to implement conditional content by store.

> The first is to leverage the theme folders per site.

Navigate to `app/design/frontend/theme/yourpackage/yourtheme/`
Duplicate this folder twice:

```
app/design/frontend/theme/yourpackage/store1/
app/design/frontend/theme/yourpackage/store2/
```

Navigate to admin panel: `admin/system_config/edit/section/design/`

**Change Current Configuration Scope** to store1 and set all of **theme** options to point to your newly created theme store1/store2.

Now both websites will use their own template & layout files which you can customize without them interfering with each other.

> The second option is simpler but long term may not be the best
>   solution.

Go to where you want to add a store conditional and drop in this if statement:

```
if( strtolower( Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() ) === 'store1' )
{
}
else if( strtolower( Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() ) === 'store2' )
{
}
```

Comment: The first option seems the most logical, I didn't think of that :-)

Thanks!